# Manipulating json before sending to a database

Tags: javascript, airtable

I'm pulling in some data from Airtable API using node and airtable.js. Im using linked fields in the airtable database. The data look like this :

```
{
            "id": "recct1MELnXEJGj6Z",
            "fields": {
                "Household": "Betts",
                "Guests": [
                    "recWONC10o06E4IN0",
                    "recLwxndGevZ7HeUG"
                ],
                "Name (from Guests)": [
                    "Margaret",
                    "Terry"
                ]
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-09-11T15:48:51.000Z"
        }
```

I would like to reformat before I push to MongoDB database so that it looks like this:

```
    {
            "id": "recct1MELnXEJGj6Z",
            "Household": "Betts",
            "Guests": [
                {
                 "_id" : "recWONC10o06E4IN0",
                 "name" : "Margaret"
                 },
                {"_id" : "recLwxndGevZ7HeUG",
                 "name" : "Terry"
                },
              ],
            "createdTime": "2021-09-11T15:48:51.000Z"
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to extract keys and values from the `fields` object, assign them directly to the JSON and then delete the `fields` object.

```js
const json = {
  "id": "recct1MELnXEJGj6Z",
  "fields": {
      "Household": "Betts",
      "Guests": [
          "recWONC10o06E4IN0",
          "recLwxndGevZ7HeUG"
      ],
      "Name (from Guests)": [
          "Margaret",
          "Terry"
      ]
  },
  "createdTime": "2021-09-11T15:48:51.000Z"
}

Object.entries(json.fields).forEach(([key, value]) => (json[key] = value));
delete json.fields;

console.log(json);
```

Or you could create a new JSON object like so:

```js
const json = {
  "id": "recct1MELnXEJGj6Z",
  "fields": {
      "Household": "Betts",
      "Guests": [
          "recWONC10o06E4IN0",
          "recLwxndGevZ7HeUG"
      ],
      "Name (from Guests)": [
          "Margaret",
          "Terry"
      ]
  },
  "createdTime": "2021-09-11T15:48:51.000Z"
}

const newJson = {...json, ...json.fields};
delete newJson.fields;
console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, unfortunately, the result I need, removes "Name (from Guests)and creates a new array where the key values are _id:name please see the original question.